# no of different ways to colour vertices of square using one or more colours from the set {R,G,B,Y} such no two adjacent vertices have the same colour

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

If have to find The number of different ways to colour the vertices of a square PQRS using one or more colours from the set {R,G,B,Y}, such that no two adjacent vertices have the same colour is?

So starting from the vertex on the top left (say P), there are 4 possible colours, as Q can't be identical to P, Q can be coloured any of 3 colours, as can R , and S too. .

thus the answer must be $4*3^3 =108$.

however, I know this is wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did wrong:

Q can't be identical to P is correct but R can be identical since it is not adjacent to P

P,R can be identical
Q,S can be identical

Solution:

Case-I
P,R are identical

->P can take any of the four colors but R doesn't have a choice since it has to
take what P takes to be identical
->Q on the other hand can take 3 colors and so can R

So, 4.3.1.3 ( S either takes what Q takes or the any one of two remaining)

Case- II
P,R are different

-> 4.3.2.2
here S has two choices ( either take what q takes or take the remaining color)
Total no. of ways = 84

Comment: Nice, this is correct!

Comment: Hello! I saw that you requested access to the Logic chat-room. However, that room is for advanced discussion of mathematical logic, so you are clearly looking for the wrong room. What did you actually want to inquire about?

Comment: I just needed to get in touch  with you regarding a question that you answered a few years ago.